# Framework/tools for rapid development of niche social networking site?

Tags: php, social-networking, rad

What kind of framework/tools do you guys have experience with that are useful for rapid development with limited resources of a niche social network that doesn't have to scale too much?  Preferably in PHP base.

Comment: I can see this rapidly descending into "what's your favourite framework"...

Answer (score 1):

The Zend Framework is well documented and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

To me rapid development in PHP calls for CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can see 
http://peoplepods.net/

it's well built

1. Full OOP
2. have sufficient query functions (no need to write SQL)
3. have sufficient social Object model

but have some problems

1. not very secured (no tokens system)
2. there is no active community